# What is the detailed syntax for the 'CREATE DATABASE' statement for VistaDB?

Tags: ado.net, embedded-database, vistadb

What is the detailed syntax for the 'CREATE DATABASE' statement for VistaDB?

The documentation only describes various procedures,functions,operators etc, but nothing on the 'CREATE DATABASE' statement. The 'create database' 'how-to' specifies hard coded values for the page size and other parameters, but can I use an ADO.NET connection string to create my database at runtime? Maybe using the 'VistaDBConnectionStringBuilder' to parse it and obtain values specified in the string.

What is the recommended way of creating the database at runtime given a connection string?